# Python run multiple prompt commands terminal

Tags: python, shell, subprocess, system

I want to run terminal command from python script. I know I can use `os.system()` call. But problem here is when I run first command I get a prompt in which I have to write next terminal command. For example:-

```
./distance vectors_bow.bin 
Enter word or sentence (EXIT to break): EXIT
```

I tried to use `os.system('./distance vectors_bow.bin & EXIT')`
but I get output `sh: 1: EXIT: not found`.

It works fine when I do the above process manually in terminal but not from python script. How to do it?

Comment: try to run command in the same way, i.e. `distance` -> `./distance`

Comment: Sorry for typo in question. Can you tell now

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly you want to run `distance` with parameter `vectors_bow.bin` and have the first input `EXIT`

try this:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
Popen(['distance', 'vectors_bow.bin'], stdin=PIPE).communicate('EXIT'.encode())
```

EDIT:
Fixed for python3 needed encode for the input parameter

Comment: You got the question correct but I am getting error : Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pawandeep/Desktop/DL_Ass2/wrd2vec_working/test_analogy.py", line 3, in <module>
    Popen(['./distance', 'vectors_bow.bin'], stdin=PIPE).communicate('EXIT')
  File "/home/pawandeep/anaconda3/envs/untitled/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 828, in communicate
    self._stdin_write(input)
  File "/home/pawandeep/anaconda3/envs/untitled/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 781, in _stdin_write
    self.stdin.write(input)
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Comment: Fixed, I was using python2. But in python3 bytes and strings are not the same thing.